# Separar arrays en objetos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente problema. Tengo este array:

```
['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro']
```

Pero ese array necesito convertirlo en un array de objetos, asi:

```
[
   {fecha: '4/7/20', registro: 'Primer registro'},
   {fecha: '4/7/20', registro: 'Segundo registro'}
]
```

Realmente no se me ocurre nada por hacer:(

Comment: Antes que nada debes confirmar que los valores siguen el mismo patron de formato. De este modo se puede procesar cada linea usando una expresion regular  si es mas complejo, o un separador fijo (espacio, por ejemplo)

Comment: Si, el patron es el mismo, no cambia absolutamente nada, solo que la fecha esta en un formato asi: 4/7/20 4:33 p. m. Y necesito separar la hora de la fecha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla para convertir un array en otro con formato distinto es usando `.map()`

```js
var datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro'];
var result = datos.map(function(item){
    var parts=item.split(" - ",2);
    return { fecha: parts[0], registro: parts[1] }
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hola F.logr solo tenia otra duda, en registro hay un identificador por ejemplo: item: registro 1. Como puedo para separar item de registro? hay " : " de intermedio

Answer (score 2):

Puede usar la función `map()` la cual recorre un array retorna un objecto diferente deseado, además de `Object.fromEntries` que convierte un array en objeto, si podrás definir tu esquema de datos si el string contiene mas datos.

```js
var datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro'];
var esquema = ['dato', 'registro']

var parseDatos = datos.map((texto) => {
     let entries = texto.split("-").map((item, index) => {
        return [esquema[index] , item.trim() ]
     })
     return Object.fromEntries(entries)
})

console.log(parseDatos)
```

De esta forma es mas escalable, si en los registros recibes otras variables.

```js
    var datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro - usuario1'];
    var esquema = ['dato', 'registro', 'usuario']

    var parseDatos = datos.map((texto) => {
         let entries = texto.split("-").map((item, index) => {
            return [esquema[index] , item.trim() ]
         })
         return Object.fromEntries(entries)
    })

    console.log(parseDatos)
```

Si los separadores son diferentes lo ideal es reemplazar por un unico separador, y convertirlo a objecto.

```js
var datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro : usuario2', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro - usuario1'];
        var esquema = ['dato', 'registro', 'usuario']

datos = datos.map((item) => {
   return item.replace(":", "-")
}) 

var parseDatos = datos.map((texto) => {
       let entries = texto.split("-").map((item, index) => {
            return [esquema[index] , item.trim() ]
       })
       return Object.fromEntries(entries)
})

        console.log(parseDatos)
```

Ahora es posible pasar este código a función para hacerlo mejor re-utilizable, asi que la dividire en 3 funciones, la primera `arrayToObject(...)` para recorrer el array , `valueToObject(...)` para validar si es posible convertirlo, `splitEntries` que convierte el dato en objecto.

De esta manera puede crear más **subObjetos** de los dato ya generados.

```js
var datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro - usuario1 : Admin'];
var esquema1 = ['dato', 'registro', 'usuario']
var esquema2 = ['nombre', 'rol']

function arrayToObject(split, array, scheme){
   let parse = array.map((data) => {
         return valueToObject(split, data, scheme)
    })
   return parse;
}

function valueToObject(split, value, scheme){
   let entries = value ? value : "";
   if(value && value.includes(split)) {
      entries = splitEntries(split,value, scheme);
   }
   return entries; 
}

function splitEntries(split, value , scheme){
   entries = value.split(split).map((item, index) => {
                return [scheme[index] , item.trim() ]
              })
   return Object.fromEntries(entries)
}

datos = arrayToObject("-", datos , esquema1);

/**
 Usuario tiene nombre y rol, asi que recorro los objectos generados
 y con al string de .usuario lo convierto en Objecto
*/
datos.forEach((item) => { 
   item.usuario = valueToObject(":", item.usuario, esquema2)
})

console.log(datos)
```

Comment: Ufff bro me has ayudado demasiado, pero tengo un problema en el cual estoy estancado, si en dado caso quiero lo mismo (mostranto tambien el usuario) pero el usuario esta separado de esta manera: `4/7/20 - Segundo registro: usuario1`

Comment: He actualizado el código, para lo que deseas debes volver a recorrer el array de los objectos generador y para cada campo que corresponda volver a convertirlo en objecto usando `split` y `Object.fromEntries`

Answer (score 0):

La solucion porpuesta por F.log esta bien, pero cambia las variables declaradas con var por const o let para controlar correctamente el scope de las variables.

```
const datos= ['4/7/20 - Primer registro', '4/7/20 - Segundo registro'];
const result = datos.map(function(item){
    const parts=item.split(" - ",2);
    return { fecha: parts[0], registro: parts[1] }
})
console.log(result);
```